# How to add "if the button is pressed" as a condition before the If statement

Tags: java, android

I am writing my first app, and inside the code i have an If statement with the condition that digit must be entered, but i want to proceed if the HOME1 button is pressed no matter if digit is entered. So should I add it in the condition, or write another IF statement? It is because even if there are no digits, user should be able to press home button.

```
    String num1 = insert1.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(num1)) {
        insert1.setError("Plese insert digit");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: you can get id of HOME1 button and in if condition check if that id, is pressed or not

Comment: take out the return.

Comment: if i take out return it does not work at all!

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting this way ...

```
// class member
boolean isHomeButtonTriggered = false;


// retrive button widget
Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_home);
home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        // set flag as true if user press the button
        isHomeButtonTriggered = true;
    }
});


if(!isHomeButtonTriggered || TextUtils.isEmpty(num1)) {
    insert1.setError("Plese insert digit");
    // revert flag to old state
    isHomeButtonTriggered = false;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know much about app developing because I'm a web developer, But what you can do is to create an statement like:

```
boolean home_pressed_or_not = false;

if(home_pressed_or_not.clicked) home_pressed_or_not = true;
```

and when ever the button is pressed the `home_pressed_or_not` value turns to true; which can tell whether the button is pressed or not

Good Luck!